# Как заставить работать AJAX в WebView Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ajax, android-sdk

Добрый день.
Необходимо обернуть мобильный сайт в нативное приложение. Сайт активно использует AJAX с обращением к удалённому серверу. Просто открытие index.html в WebView не работает. Насколько я понял политики браузера не разрешают обращение в сеть для локально загруженных страниц.
Можно как-то заставить работать такую связку?

Comment: Нет, тут другое. Описанное по ссылке решение уже опробовано.

Comment: `setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs` не помогает?

Comment: Добавьте код (инициализация WebView, загрузка ссылки). Опишите, что пробовали уже сделать.